# Clojure: time difference between now and a records SQL datetime

Tags: datetime, clojure

Trying to find out whats the best way to get the difference between the current time and a mySQL record's datetime.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
(ns clojure.example.hello
  (:require [clj-time.coerce :as coerce]
            [clj-time.local :as l]))

(let [timenow (l/local-now) ;; #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x333e8ce5 2017-02-23T21:44:11.022+11:00]
      last-update (gettimelogged :timestamp) 
      ;; returns SQL datetime which is 2017-02-23 19:20:15, 
      ;; but gets converted into #inst "2017-02-23T08:20:15.000000000-00:00"]

 (println (timenow - lastupdate)))
```

What's the best way to run a comparison between timenow and last-updated?

Also what is the best way to update the timestamp if I need to? Say if I want to lazy load it into clojure, sometime like, {:NAME "Jim" :AGE "24" :CHECKDATE "NOW()"}

Comment: difference in seconds? ms? ns?

Comment: probably different in seconds will be best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have an instant value (the value that begins with `#inst ...`), you can convert this into milliseconds using the `inst-ms` function in clojure, and then compare with the current time in milliseconds.

```
(let [db-ms (inst-ms #inst"2017-02-23T08:20:15.000000000-00:00")
      now-ms (System/currentTimeMillis)]
  (println "Difference is" (- now-ms db-ms) "ms"))
```

If you are not using clojure 1.9, you can just call `.getTime` on the `inst`:

```
(.getTime #inst"2017")
```

To insert the current time using MySQL, you have a few options, including using the built in `NOW()` function, which you can use honeysql to access.

However, for a pure jbdc-based approach, using the help of clj-time.coerce, as you're already using:

```
(defn get-sql-now []
  (-> (System/currentTimeMillis)
      coerce/from-long
      coerce/to-sql-time))

(j/insert! mysql-db "joshtable" {:name "Jim"
                                 :age 24
                                 :checkdate (get-sql-now)})
```

Comment: Problems with using inst-ms  `(let [zyx (inst-ms #inst"2017-02-23T08:20:15.000000000-00:00")] (println zyx))`. I'm getting `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: inst-ms in this context, compiling`. I'm using Clojure 1.8.0, should I be using a different version?

Comment: @Stixxxx I just updated the answer.  Call `(.getTime #inst"2017")` instead.